# MS-SQL and specific LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a table where in one column named `PATTERN` are stored patterns such as: `[11|01][22|88]333[4|0]`. Now I want to create a query similar to this:

```
SELECT mt.id
FROM dbo.MyTable mt
WHERE '11223334' LIKE mt.PATTERN
```

I know that my pattern is not correct and will not work, but I also wonder if it is possible to create query where a part `[22|88]` (two digits or another two digits) will work. This is the most important question.

Another question is if it is a good solution to store such patterns in DB and especially - to compare it in that way (please note that it is one string compared to multiple patterns, not one pattern compared to multiple strings).

**Update**

In other words - I am looking for a LIKE query which would look for more than one-digit values, i.e. `LIKE '[22|88]'` should look for values `22 or 88`, `NOT 28 or 82`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter my bad, I meant MS-SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said your pattern is not correct for what you want. `[11|01]` does not mean `11` or `01`, it means a single character that is `0`, `1` or `|`

e.g.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (VALUES ('0'), ('1'), ('|')) t (Col)
WHERE   Col LIKE '[11|01]';
```

Will return all 3 values. You need to define, so actually, to define your pattern `[11|01][22|88]333[4|0]`, the logic is much more complicated. It would be:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (VALUES 
            ('11223334'), -- MATCH
            ('11223335'), -- NO MATCH AT -------5 (NOT 0 OR 4)
            ('11283334'), -- NO MATCH AT --28---- (NOT 22 OR 88)
            ('01223334')  -- MATCH
        ) t (Col)
WHERE   Col LIKE '[01]1______'
AND     (Col LIKE '__22____' OR Col LIKE '__88____')
AND     Col LIKE '____333_'
AND     Col LIKE '_______[04]';
```

As such, I don't think you can achieve what you after with SQL Servers pattern matching alone. You will probably need to use a [clr user defined function to implement regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

I don't see any problem with storing your patterns this way if it fits your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The main problem could be a performance of such select query when storing (i think it would be about 100,000 rows) more data. Unfortunately, it seems that this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the patterns are used for but the query would be

```
SELECT mt.id
FROM dbo.MyTable mt
WHERE mt.PATTERN like '%[22|88]%'
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This query does look for values 22, 88, 82 and 28. I searching one which would look for only 22 and 88.